# How to simplify expressions contains sum of inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

In many cases involved compute the aera or volume, *Mathematica* always gives the result contains sum of inverse trigonometric functions. In fact, the result can be simplified contains only one inverse trigonometric functions, `FullSimplify` not working well.

For example:

```
res1 = FullSimplify@Area@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1 && (x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 > 4, {x, y}]

expectRes1 = Sqrt[7]/2 - Pi/2 + ArcSin[67/(64 Sqrt[2])];

N[res1 - expectRes1]


res2 = FullSimplify@Volume@RegionIntersection[Ball[{0,0,0},2], Cuboid[{1,1,1}, √2{1,1,1}]]

expectRes2 = Sqrt[2] - 1 + (97 Pi)/12 - 27 ArcTan[Sqrt[2]];

N[res2 - expectRes2]
```

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159118)

Comment: As note by @J.M., by using the rules posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/powerful-inverse-trigonometric-functions-simplify), it is posible to get a result expressed in only one inverse trigonometric result. Not exactly as in the expected result, but numerically equivalent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount`:

```
FullSimplify[res1, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount, TimeConstraint -> 60]
(* 1/2 (Sqrt[7] - ArcTan[(1541 Sqrt[7])/393]) *)

FullSimplify[res2, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount, TimeConstraint -> 60]
(* -1 + Sqrt[2] - \[Pi]/8 - 1/24 ArcTan[(4123651245286456362954203689325408073387734315097911925141171267613495287237626892084130940619316379538231060438740741988164466432224520238678407487026760 Sqrt[2])/38219844008518705060277247743675197372239901243352879627648626900184834230994760766671631647201755355168349320672368858391586410913535339715516617545787119] *)
```

In both cases you get expressions with only one trig function. If you increase the `TimeConstraint`, you will find a more compact expression for the second case. I leave this to you.

Comment: Perhaps better: `FullSimplify[res1, ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, (_ArcSin | _ArcCos | _ArcTan), {0, Infinity}] + 250 Count[#, _Log, {0, Infinity}]) &)]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that FullSimplify quits early.  You can get farther with

```
res1 = Area@
   ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 < 1 && (x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 > 4, {x, y}] // 
  FullSimplify

(*1/2 (Sqrt[7] + \[Pi] - ArcSin[1/4 (1 - Sqrt[7])] + 
   4 ArcSin[1/8 (5 - Sqrt[7])] - ArcSin[1/4 (1 + Sqrt[7])] - 
   4 ArcSin[1/8 (5 + Sqrt[7])])*)
```

Then FullSimplify individual pieces

```
    1/2 (Sqrt[7] + \[Pi] - 
   FullSimplify[
    ArcSin[1/4 (1 - Sqrt[7])] + ArcSin[1/4 (1 + Sqrt[7])]] + 
   FullSimplify[
    4 ArcSin[1/8 (5 - Sqrt[7])] - 4 ArcSin[1/8 (5 + Sqrt[7])]])  

 (*1/2 (Sqrt[7]+\[Pi]-4 ArcTan[(5 Sqrt[7])/9]-ArcCsc[4/Sqrt[7]])*)
```

Almost gets there

Answer (score 0):

For your first example:

```
res1 = FullSimplify@Area@ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 < 1 && (x + 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 > 4, {x, y}]

(* (1/2)*(Sqrt[7] + Pi - ArcSin[(1/4)*(1 - Sqrt[7])] + 
      4*ArcSin[5/8 - Sqrt[7]/8] - ArcSin[(1/4)*(1 + Sqrt[7])] - 
      4*ArcSin[(1/8)*(5 + Sqrt[7])]) *)
```

A simpler form can be obtained using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
res1r1 = FullSimplify@ComplexExpand@res1

(* (1/2)*(Sqrt[7] + Pi - ArcCot[3/Sqrt[7]] - 4*ArcTan[(5*Sqrt[7])/9]) *)
```

Further, by using a custom [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

```
res1r2 = res1r1 // FullSimplify[#, 
     ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
         100 Count[#, _ArcCot, {0, Infinity}] &)] & // ComplexExpand

(* Sqrt[7]/2 - Pi/4 + (1/4)*ArcTan[(605613*Sqrt[7])/8234159] *)
```

Although not the same form as `expectRes1`, `res1r2` has a single inverse trig function and is equivalent.

Verifying equivalence with `expectRes1`

```
expectRes1 = Sqrt[7]/2 - Pi/2 + ArcSin[67/(64 Sqrt[2])];

res1 == expectRes1 // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* True *)

res1r1 == expectRes1 // FullSimplify

(* True *)

res1r2 == expectRes1 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```